# How to always keep footer at bottom of page, dispite screen size

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project in which there many web pages. Basically I created three `div` tags for each page:

- Header
- Body (content)
- Foother

But problem is that, I declared the size of body `div` tag, which contains the main part of a page like form, any description etc.

According to my screen size, which is small, So I declared and absolute/fixed `min-height: 450px`.

But when I run this code on other computers, which have bigger screen size, then footer is misplaced (in middle of screen). So what should I do now to always keep footer at bottom of screen, dispite the size of screen?

Comment: It's good to post your code? so that based on your style rules we can adjust to work.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post your code and explain what you are trying in the code, what is working, what is not and what error messages you get.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, read these links to improve your question: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:absolute;` on the footer. By default footer is positioned relative to the `html` element, but if you apply `position:relative;` to body then the body will become reference.

To position it in the very bottom even when there is not much content, Use `height:100%;` on `body` as well as `html`.

By `position:absolute;` you will position it at the bottom of the content of html. So it will not be visible when content is very long, you'd have to scroll down to see it. But if you want it to the bottom of the screen even when the content is long then use `position:fixed;`

Below is a working snippet.

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body{
  position:relative;
}
footer{
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<footer>footer Here</footer>
```

Comment: Yeah , I done according to your suggestion ,But there is some static page , so I declared footer in those page fixed , But there is some dynamic pages too , so when I declared footer in those absolute then it did not work , so I declare footer relative in dynamic pages but In that case I Have to also declare min-height , so I declare it 500px , but It did not work on friend PC because his PC screen was bigger so footer came above from the bottom . Please help me out to this problem.Thank You somuch.

Comment: I am guessing that you are declaring min-height for body. you don't have to that . In my answer, I have positioned the footer as absolute. and every style rule that I have included in my answer is important. make sure that you are including the style for `html,body` same as I have included they are important.

Comment: If still you are facing the same problem, include a fiddle of your current code, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: I got stuck in something for some days , so neither I opened internet nor I worked on my project. Today I started again , and happily I have dont this with your help. Thank you @kittyCat

Answer (score 0):

Basically you've to use position of relative but you've to keep fluid layout without worrying about height so I have created the code below and the footer always lay below the main what ever the main content contains.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, 
html {
     height: 100%;
}
header,
main,
footer{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;

}
header {
  background: black;
  min-height: 10px;
}
main {
 min-height: 450px;
  background: gray;
}
footer {
 background: black;
 min-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```